# Extracting data from JSON log

Tags: python, json

I am a beginner when it comes to programming. I'm trying to extract elements from a `JSON` log file, but I get an error and I don't know how to deal with it.

```py
import json
with open("/Users/milosz/Desktop/logi.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
print(type(data['Objects']))
print(data)

for object in data ['Objects']:
    print(object)
```

Error:

```py
File "/Users/milosz/PycharmProjects/JsonDataExtracter/Program/Python Exracter.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(type(data['Objects']))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am sending the log below.

```json
{
    "_id": "635bd4bfc594743ce9b1a5a3",
    "dateStart": "2022-10-28T13:09:28.609Z",
    "dateFinish": "2022-10-28T13:10:23.698Z",
    "method": "customer.file.upsert",
    "request": {
        "Objects": [
            {
                "ERPId": "6915",
                "B24Id": 403772,
                "FileName": "B2B000202",
                "FileContent": "JVBERi0xLjMNJeLjz9MN",
                "B24EntityId": 3334
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Given the `JSON` snippet, you should use `data['request']['Objects']` instead.

Comment: Its not working

Comment: _"Its not working"_ doesn't help us help you. Update the question with what you are trying now and the error you are getting. Also, if you are testing using the exact `JSON` snippet you posted, it is missing two closing `}` to be valid.

Comment: Replaced: for object in data ['Objects']: to for object in data ['request']['Objects'], and I have the same error.

Comment: It probably means you are not showing us a complete snippet of your `JSON` file.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the guidance from @accdias, here is a code snippet that closes the gaps in your JSON snippet and demonstrates how to access the `Objects` section:

```
import json

json_string = """
{
    "_id": "635bd4bfc594743ce9b1a5a3",
    "dateStart": "2022-10-28T13:09:28.609Z",
    "dateFinish": "2022-10-28T13:10:23.698Z",
    "method": "customer.file.upsert",
    "request": {
        "Objects": [
            {
                "ERPId": "6915",
                "B24Id": 403772,
                "FileName": "B2B000202",
                "FileContent": "JVBERi0xLjMNJeLjz9MN",
                "B24EntityId": 3334
            }
        ]
    }
}
"""
json_dict = json.loads(json_string)
print(json_dict["request"]["Objects"])
```

Output:

```
[{'ERPId': '6915', 'B24Id': 403772, 'FileName': 'B2B000202', 'FileContent': 'JVBERi0xLjMNJeLjz9MN', 'B24EntityId': 3334}]
```